# Looking for easy USB Sound Card Chipset

Tags: usb, linux, sound, usb-device, windows

Does anyone recommend a chipset for a USB Sound Card (w/input), with readily available drivers for both linux and windows.

I am making a phone line tap to record dial modem calls in the field, for customer diagnostics. Since I am making the line tap, I can simply add such a Sound/USB chip to interface to a PC with something like Audacity. I see PCM2906 but I don't initially find drivers.

I am looking for something cheap and easily made, almost disposable. I don't want to re-invent the USB sound card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PCM2906 ([Version C](http://www.ti.com/product/pcm2906c) is the latest) is plug & play. Uses standard USB Audio (And HID) drivers already included with Windows and most Linux distros.

There is also the PCM2904, and mostly all of the PCM270x and PCM290x family.

You could also just take apart a cheap ebay usb sound card. They also use the same ASIO USB drivers.